# google apps script using SSO

Tags: google-apps-script, single-sign-on

I'm  beginner with SSO and I want use SSO based on Google Apps account to signin for my google apps script application (HTML Service).
is that possible? how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script web-apps already use Google's login system. There's just nothing to do.

Do you need something different? Have you tried the default behavior?